# Is there a way I can optimize the mongo query in order to resolve "exceeded time limit" error

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have approx. 1.1 million records in Mongo and written the below query to get the filtered data. When I am trying to run the query in mongo compass it is giving exceeded time out error.  I am new to Mongo and doesn't have much idea on how can I optimize it.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      offerCheckedDate: {
        $gte: ISODate("2022-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2022-12-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
      },
      offerAvailable: "YES",
  channelId: {
   $in: [
    1000001,
    1000000
   ]
  }
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        mobile: "$mobile",
      },
      mobile: {
        $addToSet: "$mobile",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mobile",
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "PA_DATA_REPORTING",
      localField: "mobile",
      foreignField: "mobile",
      as: "result",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$result",
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$result",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      customAppliedDate: {
        $gte: ISODate("2022-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2022-11-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      equal: {
        $eq: ["$financierId", "$appliedFinancierId"],
      },
      doc: "$$ROOT",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      equal: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        financierId: "$doc.financierId",
      },
      mobile: {
        $addToSet: "$doc.mobile",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mobile",
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.financierId",
      mobileCount: {
        $sum: 1,
      },
    },
  },
]
```

I tried adding the pipeline in $lookUp but even that didn't help. Something like below:

```
{
  from: "PA_DATA_REPORTING",
  localField: "mobile",
  foreignField: "mobile",
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        customAppliedDate: {
          $gte: ISODate("2022-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
          $lt: ISODate("2022-11-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  as: "result",
}
```

Below is the sample document I am iterating through.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$binary": {
      "base64": "fURSsmgrcSh/xWN/ENWwiA==",
      "subType": "03"
    }
  },
  "enquiryId": "e4f22813-66f9-4a09-9e92-66bacd791943",
  "mobile": "7945536728",
  "financierId": {
    "$numberLong": "280005"
  },
  "channelId": {
    "$numberLong": "1000000"
  },
  "offerAvailable": "NO",
  "offerCheckedDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1640975400000"
    }
  },
  "financierName": "Cholamandalam Finance",
  "bankOfferAmount": {
    "$numberLong": "10000"
  },
  "appliedFinancierId": {
    "$numberLong": "280004"
  },
  "appliedFinancierName": "Cholamandalam Finance",
  "paAppliedDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1640975400000"
    }
  },
  "paDisbursedDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1640975400000"
    }
  },
  "paSanctionedDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1640975400000"
    }
  },
  "customAppliedDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1640975400000"
    }
  },
  "customSanctionedDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1640975400000"
    }
  },
  "landedOnPAOfferPage": "NO",
  "_class": "com.maruti.fmp.reporting.domain.document.PAOfferDocument"
}
```

Is there any way I can optimize the query and resolve time out error.

Comment: Did you try increasing `Max Time MS` under `More Options`?

Comment: Using `_id: { mobile: "$mobile" }, mobile: { $addToSet: "$mobile" }` in `$group` does not make much sense. And `{ $group: { _id: "$mobile" }` followed by `{ $unwind: "$mobile" }` looks also pointless to me.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the explain plan (by adding option `{explain: true}`). Please provide also desired result.

Comment: @rickhg12hs- I didn't try increasing the Max time as at API gateway level timeout is set to 30 secs. Even though my query gets executed in mongo compass by increasing the time it will definitely fail at gateway level

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit I have updated the question with the sample document I have created. Also, I created unique indexes on OfferCheckedDate , CustomAppliedDate, FinancierId.

Comment: What about the second collection `PA_DATA_REPORTING`? Or is it a self-join?

Comment: this is self join

Comment: Why do you project `doc: "$$ROOT"` when you are just interested in `mobile` and `financierId`?

Comment: My thought to do something like this was- I was trying to add a field "equal" (which will either have true or false value) to all the filtered documents I have received from the previous stages so that I can just consider documents which has value {equal: true} in next stage.

{
    $match: {
      equal: true,
    },
  }

If you have any other way of doing it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you try to achieve, it is a bit difficult with only one sample document. Anyway, this one returns the same result as your query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         offerCheckedDate: {
            $gte: ISODate("2022-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2022-12-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
         },
         offerAvailable: "YES",
         channelId: { $in: [1000001, 1000000] },
      }
   },
   { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$financierId", "$appliedFinancierId"] } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$financierId",
         mobiles: { $addToSet: "$mobile" },
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         mobileCount: { $size: "$mobiles" }
      }
   }
])
```

Most likely it is not exactly what you are looking for, but in general it seems you  do a lot of redundant/useless stuff in your aggregation pipeline.

Maybe [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) is also a useful function for your use-case.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BzpkvrfZL2H)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, due to there are no information about data in database (about  inner objects (there are a lot of `unwind` operations), what type indexes exist(it lead to large query execution time), the problem could be in different places. I can just give a few advices how to optimize queries.
There is a flow how to solve performance problems:

1. There is a mongo db tool to analyze queries. Try to use [explain](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/explain/) to check the critical part of your query.

- Collection scans means all documents in a collection must be read.
- Index scans limit the number of documents that must be inspected.
  Take a look [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) how to read explain with example.

2. Add [indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)  to your database for critical parts (**do not use index for all fields** - it is necessary index only data that you need to look up) [More about query optimization](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/)
   Looks like one of the matching fields consume a lot of time in query processing. (check `offerAvailable` and `channelId`)

Comment: Hi @Rustam I did create the indexes on offerCheckedDate, customAppliedDate and financier Id. When I tried to execute EXPLAIN and the below part is taking too much time because of which I am getting exceeded time out error.

{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        financierId: "$doc.financierId",
      },
      mobile: {
        $addToSet: "$doc.mobile",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mobile",
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.financierId",
      mobileCount: {
        $sum: 1,
      },
    },
  },